# Error trying to terminate worker thread using setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, worker-thread, node-worker-threads

When trying to terminate a worker thread using setTimeout() I get the following error:

```
node:internal/worker:361
    this[kHandle].stopThread();
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stopThread')
    at Timeout.terminate [as _onTimeout] (node:internal/worker:361:19)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)

Node.js v18.12.0
```

Here is my code

```js
const { Worker } = require("node:worker_threads")
const worker = new Worker("./test.js")

const setAppTimeout = (workerName, seconds) => {
    setTimeout(workerName.terminate, seconds * 1000)
}

setAppTimeout(worker, 1)
```

When I try terminating the worker like this it works though

```js
const { Worker } = require("node:worker_threads")
const worker = new Worker("./test.js")

const setAppTimeout = (workerName, seconds) => {
    setTimeout(terminateWorker, seconds * 1000, workerName)
}
const terminateWorker = (workerName) => {
    workerName.terminate()
}

setAppTimeout(worker, 1)
```

Can someone tell me why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are loosing the `this` context to `worker` when passing `worker.terminate` to `setTimeout`.

What you can do is to `.bind` the `.terminate` method to the `worker` object and pass the bound function:

```
const setAppTimeout = (workerName, seconds) => {
  setTimeout(workerName.terminate.bind(workerName), seconds * 1000);
}
```

Read more about `this` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
And more about `.bind` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), too